# How to execute a command without tkinter GUI freezing

Tags: python, tkinter, ngrok, os.system, tkinter-button

I've been working on a GUI, and one command I need to execute is ngrok.exe. But whenever I use `os.system(f"ngrok.exe http --basic-auth {base_creds} file:///Mal_Files")` it freezes the GUI and wont continue working. Is there any way to fix this? I've heard threads could help but i dont know anything about them.

CODE

```py
    def start_ngrok():
        ngrok_creds = open("tools/ngrok_creds.txt", "r")
        ngrok_creds_lines = ngrok_creds.readlines()
        base_creds = ngrok_creds_lines[0]
        ngrok_creds.close()
        try:    
          os.system(f"ngrok.exe http --basic-auth {base_creds} file:///Mal_Files")  
          ngrok_started_q = True
        except:
          print("Error staring ngrok server, try again later.")
          ngrok_started_q = False
          os.kill
    
# Button to start ngrok code
run_ngrok = tkinter.Button(base_frame, text="Start Ngrok",command=Main.start_ngrok, width=20)
base_frame.create_window(80, 20, window=run_ngrok)
```

Comment: Use `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`

Comment: already tried, no luck unless i missed somthing

Comment: Even if you use threads here, you need to wait to interpret the result anyway don't you ? If you want the mainloop of the GUI to run you can execute the command in a thread with your function but you'll need to call another function at some point to extract the result and interpret it.

Comment: Post what you have tried on using `subprocess` and the error you came across.

Comment: well @acw1668 i assume subprocess was updated to not have some things while some were also moved to the os module. below is the following commands where i could not see the output or it would freeze the GUI

subprocess.Popen()
os.popen()
os.system()
subprocess.check_output()
ect.